# Is it possible to assign an operation to the same variable, which is used in operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an operation in tensorflow which looks like follows:

`x = tf.where(tf.is_nan(x), tf.zeros_like(x), x)`

Is this possible, as the operation changes the new variable x continuously, while simultaneously using it for code execution?

Comment: Can you make an example with input and expected output?

Comment: E.g. my x is a tensor of shape [a, b, c, d], and the expected output is also [a, b, c, d]. The tf.where checks the condition (element-wise) in the first argument, and if True, replaces the element with the respective element from the second argument. If False, it replaces the element with the respective element from the third argument. I think tensorflow does this element-wise, so it should not be a problem to do as stated in the question?

Comment: Have you tested it already? Do you get any error or unexpected results?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to reuse variable names in Python, regardless of whether TensorFlow is used or not. (The previous tensor associated with `x` still exists, but cannot be accessed in code via `x` anymore, as it has been assigned a new value. The `x` to the left of `=` is really a different tensor as the `x` used on the right.)

You could rewrite your code as

```
y = tf.where(tf.is_nan(x), tf.zeros_like(x), x)
```

and it would have the same meaning, as long as, for the rest of the code, you use `y` instead of `x`.